# View Multiple results Based On Semi-colon delimeter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to view multiple results using a semi-colon character delimiter. I can only view results based on one ID. But I would like to find multiple Id's. How can I implement the semi-colon/space/comma to display all ID's with the text from the text box.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string searching)
{
    return PartialView("Index", db.tblAuditFile2
        .Where(x => x.RefNo.Contains(searching))
        .ToList());
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Audit", FormMethod.Get)) { @Html.TextBox("searching")
<input type="submit" value="Search" /> }

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RefNo)
    </th>
    <th>
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FileName)
    </th>
    <th>
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TransDate)
    </th>
  </tr>

  @foreach (var item in Model) {
  <tr>
    <td>
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.model.RefNo))
    </td>
    <td>
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FileName)
    </td>
    <td>
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TransDate)
    </td>
  </tr>
  }
</table>
```

Comment: Convert the string to an array (using `String.Split()`) so that you can use `tblAuditFile2.Where(x => yourArray.Contains(x.RefNo))`

Comment: THANKS! PERFECT.

Answer (score 1):

You can first use Split() to split the search values. (I think RefNo is integer?). ie:

```
public ActionResult Index(string searching)
{
    var searchItems = searching.Split( new char[] {';',',',' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    return PartialView("Index",
        db.tblAuditFile2.Where(x=>searchItems.Contains(x.RefNo))
          .ToList());
}
```

Comment: @user8155123, :) Then simply do not convert to int. Anyway editing for you. BTW, it would also help, when there is an error, instead of saying "getting error", share the error message.

Comment: Thanks, managed to get it working though. Was a simple error due to converting to int